# Having troubles fitting the UIImageView and Label into Scroll View

Tags: objective-c, view, scrollable

I want to fit the Image + Label into Scrollable View.

It looks like so [My setup](https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/3528454/StackOverflow/output1.png)

So trouble here is that width of the picture and the label did not match the screen width.

I tried to change the UIImageView width from 400 to 300 or so, BUT those changes either wont take the effect(if above 300), OR those changes make label disappear (with width setted up on 300 or below). [Observe](https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/3528454/StackOverflow/output2.jpg).

Funny thing is - label actually appears when you see view hierarchy, even though it looks kinda distorted. But no label on the iOS screen for you, sir.

I also tried to set equal width and height from the superview, but this option just disabling scroll, making view strictly fit the screen (label appears to be cropped)

I want the label to be nice and scrollable, but I also want to see it on the screen. Too much to ask?

EDIT: I just tried removing Auto-layout and got the same as with auto-layout. (click "Observe" link to take a look again, exact same situation) Could somebody explain why?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is quite a simple fix. For the image, you should use equal width & center horizontally; however, make sure you use a fixed width. For the image to look nice, play with the scale modes - I find Aspect Fit/Fill work best.

The label should also be equal width & centered horizontally. You may need to calculate the height of the label programmatically if the text isn't always going to be the same size.

Comment: after centring horizontally I got same effect - Image is fine, but no Label visible :-/

Answer (score 0):

So the answer to my particular question was - shortening the actual text that is passed to the label.
Apparently UIScrollView can't handle stuff with crazy abnormal heights (I was passing a huuuge text to it) So in my particular situation solution was - shorten the text. Now it works like a charm (even though I still need to play a little with constraints to get rid of the warnings and stuff)